# SQL matching IDs from different columns with their respective username

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table containing the columns user_id and lastreply_by_user_id and I'm looking for a way to match their columns with their username from the user table with id.

```
SELECT
   table_threads.*,
   table_users.username
FROM
  threads AS table_threads
  INNER JOIN users as table_users ON table_threads.user_id = table_users.id
  OR table_threads.lastreply_by_user_id = table_users.id
WHERE  
   table_threads.category_id = :category_id
```

This is the code I have right now but this at the moment creates duplicate entries instead of one merged.

Just started with SQL recently and found the JOIN commands maybe it isn't the right one just point me in the right direction and I'll be thankful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need two joins to the same `user` table for that: one to connect by `user_id`, and one more to connect by `lastreply_by_user_id`. Use table aliases for disambiguation:

```
SELECT
   t.*,
   u.username as user_name,
   r.username as last_reply_name
FROM
  threads AS t
  INNER JOIN users as u ON t.user_id = u.id              -- actual user
  INNER JOIN users as r ON t.lastreply_by_user_id = r.id -- reply user
WHERE  
   table_threads.category_id = :category_id
```